# Changing login / logout page in .NET Core 2.2 using identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have done this differently in every version of .net core however now in 2.2 I cannot get my code to redirect correctly.

Here's what I am using in the **startup.cs** as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source):

*(This is a default new and clean project)*

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
      options.AllowAreas = true;
      options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
      options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
    });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
  {
    options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
  });
```

Changing the login or logout path currently does nothing. Any suggestions here as to what I may be missing?

Comment: Are you using Razor Identity approach or MVC approach?

Comment: @TanvirArjel This is using RazorPages.

Comment: Okay! Then instead of `/Identity/Account/Login` on which page you are trying to redirect if user not authenticated?

Comment: Are you sure its not working? Have checked any other things not related to this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188615/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-dreamtek).

Answer (score 2):

Okay! Problem is identified. If you use `.AddDefaultUI()` with identity service registration then overriding the default `options.LoginPath` would not work. So to use your custom login path for unauthorized user redirection, comment out the `.AddDefaultUI()` as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                //.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4) <-- you have to comment out this
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now it should work. Here is the [Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1414)

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent investigating this (+1). I am unsure why a downvote because people wont ever explain their thoughts on here. I am aware of the issues with DefaultUI but had already commented this out before posting to no effect.

Comment: Now I am outside my computer. Surely I shall help you whenever back to my computer.